# Polymer: re-using HTML snippet in an element

Tags: import, polymer, polymer-1.0, html-imports

I am working on a set of Polymer elements (buttons in this particular case) some of which should re-use the same HTML snippet. A structure for a custom button is as follows:

```
...
<link rel="import" href="button-base.html" id="content">
<link rel="import" href="styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="behavior.html">

<dom-module id="dg-button">
  <template>
    <style include="button-styles"></style>
    <!-- HERE I want the content of button-base.html -->
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'custom-button',
      behaviors: [DG.ButtonBehavior]
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Styles and behavior work as they should.

The problem is: I am not sure how to get content of `button-base.html` into the specified place of the local DOM without defining `button-base` as yet another element and then using it as `<button-base></button-base>`.

The reasons I want to avoid converting it to the new element are:

- I want the content of `button-base` to be a first-class citizen of the `custom-button` element's local DOM so that all the methods defined in the behavior would still apply using just `this.myMethod()` for buttons that do not import `button-base` and rather use custom local DOM.
- I need to be able to declaratively set properties on this new `custom-button` so that they get reflected on DOM elements within `button-base.html` automatically.

For example, the content of the `button-base.html` is as follows:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<paper-button id="internalButton" raised$="[[raised]]">
  <span id="defaultContent">
    <content></content>
  </span>
</paper-button>
```

I would like to set `raised` on my `custom-button` in a way that it gets mapped to `paper-button` automatically without proxying all of the possible attributes through a new element (in case I define `base-button` as a new element and import it as `<base-button></base-button>` in `custom-button`).

Any ideas on how to make this import work?

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, but i don't see the real problem. With `button-base` as element you'll need to call `this.$.button.method` and add `behavior` inside `button`(if needed) instead of in the element. This will make your snippet reusable, methods reusable(either from inside button or from behavior). Yes, you might need to split your current behavior into two different behaviors.

Comment: Thanks, @a1626. This is sort of a workaround imo. But I have also updated the question with information about the properties. The need of mapping all the possible properties from the root `custom-button` all the way to interns of `base-button` make the whole thing unnecessary overcomplicated.

Comment: You can avoid re-declaring properties by keeping them in a behavior but i don't think there's an alternate to binding from parent to child. Even Polymer elements has such bindings

Comment: @a1626 setting properties declaratively (with attributes) without declaring them in `properties` is a totally working scenario. When I have a `paper-button` in my element's local DOM, I can set it's properties just with attributes on the host element. This way I set only those attributes that I need on this particular element in this particular scenario and avoid listing all the possible attributes in `properties`

Comment: Correct, that is also one way of doing it, but i think in that case they'll not be listed in documentation if you create one(not sure though)

Comment: Of course. They won't. But I don't need them to be. It might happen that I never use all the properties of `paper-button` on any instance of my host element. So no need to declare all the possible options in this case – it's enough to know that all the properties declared on `paper-button` can be proxied to it from the host element. And *this* I can write in the documentation ;)

Comment: Did you try to use document.importNode to inject your imported base-button HTML code in the dg-button template?